# How to select different implementation of MPI_Bcast function in OpenMPI

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

In Open MPI the Broadcast function have various implementation like Flat tree, Chain tree, Binomial, Binary, Split-binary, K-Chain tree.

How do I tell the Open MPI to use one of these implementations?

[This link does not give any information about it](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.1/man3/MPI_Bcast.3.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
mpirun --mca coll_tuned_use_dynamic_rules true --mca coll_tuned_bcast_algorithm <algo> ...
```

where  can be found from `ompi_info --all`:

```
MCA coll tuned: parameter "coll_tuned_bcast_algorithm" (current value: "ignore", data source: default, level: 5 tuner/detail, type: int)
                          Which bcast algorithm is used. Can be locked down to choice of: 0 ignore, 1 basic linear, 2 chain, 3: pipeline, 4: split binary tree, 5: binary tree, 6: binomial tree, 7: knomial tree, 8: scatter_allgather, 9: scatter_allgather_ring. Only relevant if coll_tuned_use_dynamic_rules is true.
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to select the implementation at runtime?

Comment: I am not sure. you can try setting the `OMPI_MCA_coll_tuned_bcast_algorithm" environment variable, but you will need to create and use a new communicator after that. I did not test this and I am not even sure this is enough.